# how can I embed Eclipse components/plugins into my Java app?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to embed Eclipse plugins and componenets into my application? Sort of like how in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of viewpoints to this question. Generally, including Eclipse plug-ins is possible (it's all Java in the end). However, as Eclipse is a large framework, plug-ins will make excessive usage of framework specific calls. The whole invocation process is unique in Eclipse. In addition, the GUI will be based on SWT/JFace. You might investigate which dependencies the plug-in has and include all of these, but this will give you quite a large overhead of includes.

You can of course rip them apart and implement the "business logic", but **there's no plug and play**!

If you used Eclipse RCP as the base for your Java application things are of course a lot easier.

Comment: can you elaborate on how things will be easier? I have already been scarred with trying to learn Netbeans.

Comment: Would that link be helpful? http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jules, I really think the way to go is putting your application into an Eclipse plug-in and making this new plugin an executable application.

See the following link on how to configure your plugin to do that : http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_application%3F

But in all cases you have to take a great care on the dependencies that can bring you a lot of overhead...

Comment: will the plugin executable run like any other java app on any os? can the dependencies be packaged?

Comment: The created jar would. However, the common way with Eclipse is to create platform specific runtime binaries, see guide here: http://wadeawalker.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/tutorial-creating-native-binary-executables-for-multi-platform-java-apps-with-opengl-and-eclipse-rcp/

Eclipse allows for packaging the dependencies. You can even use the eclipse update manager to handle dependencies.

Comment: why noy just use eclipse rcp ? is creating plugin faster?

Comment: @Kim Jong Woo: As I already mentioned, if you used an RCP application as your basis, things would be a lot easier :)